# Activiti: no processes deployed with key 'oneVacationProcess'

Tags: java, spring, activiti

i want to use activiti in spring mvc. my java config for activiti is below.
when i run project this exception `no processes deployed with key` throw. i put `one-vacation-process.bpmn20.xml` in resources folder. what is my problem? thanks for help.

```
  @Configuration
  public class ActivitiConfig {

@Bean
public ProcessEngine processEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl pec, ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean pe = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
    pe.setProcessEngineConfiguration(pec);
    pe.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    return pe.getObject();
}

@Bean
public ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl getProcessEngineConfiguration(
        DataSource dataSource,
        PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
        ApplicationContext context) {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration pec = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();

    pec.setDataSource(dataSource);
    pec.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");
    pec.setJobExecutorActivate(true);
    pec.setHistory("full");
    pec.setMailServerPort(2025);
    pec.setDatabaseType("mysql");

    pec.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    pec.setApplicationContext(context);

    return pec;
}

@Bean
public RuntimeService getRuntimeService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    return processEngine.getRuntimeService();
}
@Bean
public TaskService taskService(ProcessEngine processEngine) throws Exception {
    return processEngine.getTaskService();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy your process first.

There is API for different usecases, here I deploy a process where `resourceName` is the name of the process xml (e.g. `one-vacation-process.bpmn20.xml`) and `content` the actual file content as string.

```
RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
DeploymentBuilder builder = repositoryService.createDeployment().addString(resourceName, content);
builder.enableDuplicateFiltering().deploy();
```

Have a look at `org.activiti.engine.repository.DeploymentBuilder` where there is API like:

```
DeploymentBuilder addInputStream(String resourceName, InputStream inputStream);
DeploymentBuilder addClasspathResource(String resource);
DeploymentBuilder addString(String resourceName, String text);
DeploymentBuilder addZipInputStream(ZipInputStream zipInputStream);
DeploymentBuilder addBpmnModel(String resourceName, BpmnModel bpmnModel);
```